# iOS & Swift - Using a premade SQLite database

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite

I was recently porting an Android app over to iOS (manually of course, it's more fun that way) and all was well until I realized that databases are slightly trickier on iOS than on Android. I managed to set everything up... except I'm not sure where to place my .sqlite file so as to be able to access it from my Swift code. I'm using the SQLite.swift library, which is probably an important thing to note :)

Any help? Appreciated in advance!